# International Keyboard -layouts over X -- how to set them up?

Tags: keyboard-layout, bug-reporting, debian, x11, internationalization

*I have asked a related question in different sites such as [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/418/brauche-den-deutsch-support-mit-meiner-tastatur) in German and a related thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/462510/dvorak-international-dead-keys-in-debian), a different case in the latter though. The `# dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` is firing `WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowcomma"`, some bug?*

I almost solved the question [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/420/887), basically: `"/etc/default/keyboard"` -modification and one-line `"$ setxkbmap -option grp:caps_toggle -variant dvorak-intl,nodeadkeys, us,de,no &"` -- but the layout-settings get reseted after reboot. I use Debian but I believe the same settings apply to Ubuntu hence asking here.

**Helper questions**

> 1. So how can I get settings to stay after rebooting? Or `# service gdm3 restart`?
> 2. Or better how can I configure international keyboard -layouts system wide?
> 3. What about user-centric keyboard -configuration?

Comment: Do the settings get reset when you log in and out again, without resetting?

Answer (score 1):

I feel the solution is close to some trial below. I am getting some WARNING now with default keyboard -adjusting, third trial, so cannot test things fully. I am co-operating with guys such as Trem.* in #Debian (Freenode), we haven't yet found a solution but below some of our working to diagnose the issue. The `# dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` should be enough to tune KBD but not sure with CapsLk -toggling, anyway some trials below.

> **Trial 1: not working**
>
> > ```
> > $ cat /etc/default/keyboard
> >
> > XKBMODEL="pc105"
> > XKBLAYOUT="us,de,no"
> > XKBVARIANT="dvorak-intl,nodeadkeys,"
> > XKBOPTIONS="grp:caps_toggle"
> > ```
>
> **Trial 2: not working**
>
> The basic idea is to configure the X -configuration files in certain level. For some reason, the keyboard settings get overwritten by some other settings, even though trying almost the highest level ie 98.
>
> > ```
> > # echo "setxkbmap -option grp:caps_toggle -variant dvorak-intl,nodeadkeys, us,de,no &">>/etc/X11/Xsession.d/39x11-keyboard
> > # echo "exec /etc/X11/Xsession.d/39x11-keyboard" >>/etc/X11/Xsession.d/99x11-common_start
> > ```
> >
> > Then restarting-X does not work which is clear because the Caps-Lock -toggle not working -- it was because the settings got over-written `# echo 'echo "Did run 001">/tmp/KBDrunned001' >>/39x11-keyboard.` So
> >
> > ```
> > # mv /etc/X11/Xsession.d/39x11-keyboard /etc/X11/Xsession.d/98x11-keyboard
> > ```
> >
> > It did not work because the settings got over-written. Apparently some 99-level-thing or other 98-level-thing overwrites the keyboard -settings.
>
> **Trial 3: not working**
>
> > It fires error in the position after setting up the font size, keeping default 16, did not
> >     even ask about layouts or Cap-Lock -toggling.
> >
> > ```
> > # dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
> > WARNING: Unknown X keysym "dead_belowcomma"
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

Solution #1, easy: go to keyboard layout settings, click on "Options", select the desired Caps Lock behaviour:

[image]

Solution #2, easy: put that command into your profile's startup. Press the win key and type `startup`, then use it to add the full command.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, .profile is for shell initialisation, it is not read until you start a terminal. Either use the GUI as described above, or look into the `.config/autostart/` directory.

Comment: Just as I have described above. Press the Win key to show the Unity dialog, then type "startup" -- the icon for the startup settings should appear. Select it and you are at the screenshot above. I have added a screenshot above.

Comment: Cool, it would have saved us some time if you did mention that earlier (your question *Is it gnome* made me think that you assume that I am using Gnome). Open a terminal, type `gnome-control-center` and choose "keyboard layout".

Comment: In the gnome-control-center, I did just a shortcut F1 to the command. It does not solve the problem but I need just to remember hit F1 in the start.